# How to override nested dependency package version?

Tags: yarnpkg

Somewhere in my yarn.lock file:

```
reactpack@^0.9.0:
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/reactpack/-/reactpack-0.9.0.tgz#ee3b7692a2c99231d5c235af87ad33d0d0cb6434"
  dependencies:
    ...
    react-hot-loader "^1.3.0"
    ...
```

I want to change react-hot-loader to "3.0.0-beta.6".
I tried to add following part to package.json:

```
"resolutions": {
  "react-hot-loader": "3.0.0-beta.6"
}
```

but it is ignored by yarn :(.
Runing `yarn --flat` wants to flatten ALL packages (which is not what I want)...

Any other alternatives?

Comment: what is the output of `yarn why react-hot-loader`? add it to the question.